# Calendar date selection patterns

Tags: mobile, calendar

If user needs to apply leave with a combination of AM, PM and full day leaves...what is the best practice or pattern I can follow?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can use background images, I'd make one where the bottom half is green, indicating afternoons, and one with the top half green, indicating mornings.